# Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'SimpleNotificationsModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, angular-cli

I've installed [angular2-notifications](https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications) in my Angular 4 project and everything went fine, but when I changed machine I got the following issue when trying to compile using `ng serve`:

> ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Calling function 'SimpleNotificationsModule', function calls are not
>   supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference
>   to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   myapp/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   myapp/src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading about [similar issues on github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3707) I finally found the solution:

For some reason IntelliJ/Webstorm tend to import this package as:

```
import { SimpleNotificationsModule } from 'angular2-notifications/dist';
```

It should be instead:

```
import { SimpleNotificationsModule } from 'angular2-notifications';
```

*thanks **MattsSe** for posting this solution on GitHub.*